# "Puzzlescript" Coding language

Tags: discussion

There is a coding language known as "Puzzlescript" that was developed by Steven Lavelle and is intended to be used to create short puzzle games.

Would it be acceptable to write the code for a puzzle game and post its link as a puzzle (with appropriate context, of course) on Puzzling SE?

Comment: I am not sure how a puzzle maintained on some outside source will be taken by the community as it's not SE which is maintaining it but a third party. That's what I think Puzzlescript does. But, you can wait for someone to answer that.

Comment: Mayby post an example here on meta?

Comment: Okay, here's an example of a game that I made. The goal of the game is to move your snake with the arrow keys, collect all of the dots, and then leave.  http://www.puzzlescript.net/play.html?p=6642bf1b37f18bf77e75

Comment: You may want to look at the answers to [this question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4992).  In general, we try to keep puzzles self-contained on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: Is there a reasonable "Answer" to a puzzle game like this?

Comment: Not really. But then again, puzzling SE is supposed to be more casual, and questions can be posed mostly for the pleasure of the viewers, so... perhaps an answer is unnecessary?

Comment: Make the "puzzle" figuring out how to represent the puzzle represented by the code in the least code possible. BAM! The long-awaited Puzzling-PPCG crossover!